# XSLT: Removing &gt; from String

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a string in xslt whose value is the following

```
&lt;TSE_Response>
```

I want to replace it with

```
&lt;TSE_Response&gt;
```

Experts please help

Comment: It's the same character.

Comment: Although both are same but in the output we need the literal not the symbol. Thanks

Comment: Are you outputing just "text" or "xml" (i.e what "method" are you using on the "xsl:output" element)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the XSLT level, there is no distinction between `">"` and `"&gt;"`: they are the same character, displayed ("serialized") in different ways. XSLT assumes when you are outputting XML that it's going to be processed by a proper conformant XML parser, which doesn't make any distinction between `">"` and `"&gt;"`, so it assumes that there is no reason you should care which representation is chosen.

You haven't explained why you do care about the distinction; the only reason I can think of is that the data is going to be read by some poorly-designed software in which case the answer might be to fix that software. If you can't do that, there are workarounds in XSLT using disable-output-escaping or (in XSLT 2.0) character maps - but I'd like to understand your requirement before recommending such solutions.